# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() on Samsung devices

Tags: android, service, background, samsung-mobile

I have an issue with background working of service on Samsung devices.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1881)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

[image]

Of course, after starting the service I call Service.startForeground() and there are no problems on other devices just only Samsung device.

Is anybody know the reason and how to work around of this issue?

I have found similar problem in Zopim SDK https://chat.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004395368-Crash-on-Android-8-in-Android-SDK-1-4-2

Comment: probably on some devices it is taking more time before call `Service.startForeground()`, as the time betweene those 2 calls is limited

Comment: I also had the same issue but i fixed it. Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571182/service-stops-working-when-app-gets-closed/55571560#55571560. It might help you. You can also check sample code here: https://filebin.net/p5jv54ow5vl4y4gt/ServiceSample.zip?t=p6vqlepa

Comment: are you doing any work before calling `Service.startForeground()` ? Please add your service class

Comment: @ManoharReddy, the first call in onCreate() of service is startForeground(). Sorry, I cant show the code, it is under NDA, but it looks like ... public void onCreate() { startForeground(...) } ...

Comment: @Nik: It doesn't related to Samsung devices. As you mentioned, the problem comes from android 8 service limitations. Do you show a notification in `startForeground()`?

Comment: Just on the off-chance, does anything in this AOSP issue help? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072

Comment: did you try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467063/5444161]

Comment: Are you facing this issue in FirebaseMessagingService service?

Comment: @aminography of course I show notifications just after service was created

Comment: @aminography we have many thousand users, this problem happens only on samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 1.4.4

> Fixed a bug in the ChatWidgetService lifecycle handling
>   that caused RemoteServiceException.

https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android-chat-sdk/releasenotes#version-1.4.4